# Prevent non-admin accounts editing DNS records

Tags: macos, security, dns, system-settings, monterey

Is it possible to prevent any non-admin users in MacOS Monterey from being able to change DNS in System Preferences?

I know that the user is required to enter admin login details when they attempt it, but I'd prefer it if these settings could only be changed when actually logged in to an admin user account.

Comment: Technically speaking non-admin users can‘t change these entries, it always requires an admin account to do so. What are you trying to prevent here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any restriction you add as an admin can be removed as an admin. You will need to ensure regular users never know the name and password for an admin user in this case.